# How can I use the OneDrive Web picker when my redirect URLs include unique user ids?

Tags: javascript, redirect, onedrive

I am trying to add the OneDrive Web picker SDK (Javascript) to my website. There is a "redirect URL" that must be added for each page on which the picker is located. The problem I'm having is that my URL is, e.g., `www.mysite.com/user/382982389745`. Now, I can't reasonably be expected to add a redirect URL for each user in my database. So, how can I handle this issue since the redirect URL must match exactly to the page that has the file picker?

Comment: within javascript you can get the url of the current page with `window.location.href`, can't you use that?

Comment: The redirect URLs have to be predefined on my microsoft account.

Comment: aah ok, I didn't know that :P, well, than I have no clue, I'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

Hi am facing the same Problem, After spending few hours I am able to fix this problem.

Please follow the steps.

Step 1)
Go to the Link Download the File Js file and save it
https://js.live.net/v6.0/OneDrive.js

Step 2) Unminfiy the js file using any of the online tool

Step 3) Replace Line 2265 with 
--  if (!a) a = rf(document.location.origin);

Step 4) Save Js File and use in your Project

Step 5) In API set the Redirect URL as Base URL of the Application

or -- http://example.com

Here we go.. It will fix you probem. It work on all page of the same Base URL.

If you still have any query write to me - shobhitwalia@gmail.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251974/how-to-handle-multiple-tenants-with-onedrive-picker i am also facing same issue can u help me

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with a similar problem. 
My solution was to add the Id as a parameter which seemed to work.

In your case change the url to www.mysite.com/user?id=382982389745 and then the redirect url to www.mysite.com/user