# Need a way to allow web pages with dynamic URLs to embed the OneDrive filepicker

Tags: javascript, onedrive, filepicker

The OneDrive unified file picker (https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/unified-javascript-picker-saver.htm) expects predefined static URL(s) to be specified as Redirect URL(s), but we need to embed the file picker in an application (Open edX, a MOOC) on multiple course content pages and those pages do not have predefined static URLs. How can we embed the file picker in such pages?

I looked at another question here with a similar but different issue ([How can I use the OneDrive Web picker when my redirect URLs include unique user ids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448226/how-can-i-use-the-onedrive-web-picker-when-my-redirect-urls-include-unique-user)). In their case, the suggested solution was to change the URL structure to use query string params. In our case, we are developing a plugin for Open edX, so we do not have control over the URL structure or redirection. So that solution will not work for us.